# requests.post() output differs in compiler vs interpreter

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a simple Python program that works fine using the Python interpreter. Code is like:

```
import requests
import json
headers = {'accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
data = { 'key':'value'}
auth = ('user','password')
url = '192.168.123.123'

response = requests.post(url, data = data, headers=headers, auth = auth)
print(response.status_code)
```

The web server returns 200 which is the OK-code.

I want to run this as a compiled program, like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import requests
import json
headers = {'accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
data = { 'key':'value'}
auth = ('user','password')
url = '192.168.123.123'

def main ()
    response = requests.post(url, data = data, headers=headers, auth = auth)

print(response.status_code)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Strangely, the webserver now returns 500 for not being ready. I have tried some time delays but I cannot fix this. Obviously, this could be a problem specific to this server. Any other ideas?

The output given by the interpreter is different from the compiler output

Comment: Can you check the code you have pasted is exactly what you are running? For example, the code you put here doesn't have `:` after `def main ()`. The `print` statement appears to be outside of `main`, which would be a problem, but not sure whether that's your real code or whether it's an indentation issue when you pasted the code here.

Comment: 500 means something is broken on the server side. So both methods should fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import urllib.request
import json

headers = {'accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
data = json.dumps({'key': 'value'}).encode('utf-8')
auth = ('user', 'password')
url = 'http://192.168.123.123'

def main():
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    password_mgr = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
    password_mgr.add_password(None, url, auth[0], auth[1])
    handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)

    try:
        response = opener.open(req)
        print(response.getcode())
        response.close()
    except urllib.request.HTTPError as e:
        print(e.code)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

That is some corrected code that does not produce any errors. I will detail below everything I changed.

First, I changed `requests` to `urllib.request` because `requests` was being annoying and causing some very odd errors. But `urllib.request` seems to be a fine substitue here. Presumably, this wasn't you're issue if the other thingy worked fine.

Second, I added a colon after `def main()`. That could have been your whole issue.

Finally, mainly because I'm using the `urllib.request` instead of `requests` I had to change your whole function. This probably isn't what caused your error since the `requests` module worked just fine on your other thingy. The one thing that might be an issue what that the `print()` statement was outside of the `main()` function. Anyways, I changed it from:

`def main ()`

```
`response = requests.post(url, data = data, headers=headers, auth = auth)`
```

`print(response.status_code)`

And I made it into:

```
def main():
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=data, headers=headers)
password_mgr = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_mgr.add_password(None, url, auth[0], auth[1])
handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)

try:
    response = opener.open(req)
    print(response.getcode())
    response.close()
except urllib.request.HTTPError as e:
    print(e.code)
```

Most likely, the second thing and the third thing is what got you as its enough to cause a problem and wasn't in the other one. The first and third are mostly just me trying to get around the annoying `requests` module, which doesn't seem to be your problem since the oter thingy had `requests` too. There is the `print()` statement being outside of the `main()` function issue causing it not to `print()` since it will be executed before the request is made. Then if the request is in fact made it will never be printed (presuming your program didn't stop because of an error already). As to why I included the first? I just wanted to explain everything I changed.